# Chromatic polynomial of planar graphs

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

The chromatic polynomial of a graph counts the number of its (proper) vertex k-colorings. (more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial))

Draw a planar graph $G$ with the maximum number of vertices such that the chromatic polynomial of $G$ is equal to the chromatic polynomial of $\overline{G}$.

I can draw some examples which satisfy the condition but I do not know how to get to the graph with the maximum number of vertices which have the above feature.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=\lvert G \rvert $ and $p_G(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i a_i x^{n-i}$ be the chromatic polynomial of $G$.

As you can see in the Wikipedia article that you linked (and you can prove by induction using the contraction-deletion relation) $a_1=e(G)$ is the number of edges in $G$.

Now observe that $e(G) + e(\bar{G})=\binom{n}{2}$ and since the chromatic polynomial is the same we mush have $e(G)=\frac{1}{2} \binom{n}{2}$.

But you know that $G$ is a planar graph and so $e(G) \leq 3n-6$. Solving the inequality $\frac{1}{2} \binom{n}{2} \leq 3n-6$ gives you $n\leq 10$. You can further eliminate $n=10$ because in this case $\binom{10}{2}$ is not divisible by $2$, so maximal such graph has at most $9$ vertices. From here on, finding a maximal example should be a matter of some casework.

Comment: WoW, this is a very nice idea. I think maybe there is an example with 9 vertices and 18 edges such that $G$=$\overline{G}$

Comment: Unfortunately, there are such graphs of order $9$, but they are non-planar because they contain $K_5$ (see this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02309.pdf). On the other hand, there are planar self-complementary graphs of order $8$, so the answer to your question is $8$ or $9$.